# How to make a selection equivalent of not submitted?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using a bootstrap form to submit data to a php page.  I want that when the user doesn't make a particular selection from the given options, the form should submit either as or as null and not "SELECT ONE".  Part of the code is given below.  All the other data fields follow the same logic.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="smoking">Smoking Habits</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="smoking" id="smoking" required>
        <option data-hidden="true">SELECT ONE</option>
        <option>Smoker</option>
        <option>Non-smoker</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `<option>` only uses the text content as the data to submit if there is no `value` attribute.

You can add a value attribute to the option element, but the value has to be a string. It can be an empty string.

There is no native way to represent `null` in a HTML form.

```
<option data-hidden="true" value="">SELECT ONE</option>
```